# Finding true error between two curves

Tags: error

In the image below, the **orange** curve is the true function, the **dots** are samples from the true function plus a unit variance gaussian, while the **blue** curve are the estimated function using linear regression with polynomial basis.

[image: Graph]

I want to find a meaningful way to compute the true error between the blue and orange curves. I used $$
\epsilon=\|f(x)-\hat f(x)\|_2
$$
where $f(x), \hat f(x)$ are the vector of all the outputs in the interval and $x$ consists of small increments (points) in the X-axis.
The problem is that the true error increases as I let the increments become small to smoothen the plot of the curve. What shall I divide with my true error function to make them more meaningful like staying between 0 and 1 for example?

Comment: Are you multiplying your point-estimates by the "dx" you are using? If not, that would certainly be a reason your error is diverging with decreasing stepsize.

Comment: @costrom unfortunately no, I am simply using the function values obtained on those many x points in my error function. May I ask where should I place those dx in my function?

Comment: This question may be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675833/find-the-distance-between-2-functions

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "true error"?  After all, you already have an estimate of the error between your polynomial fit and the data.

Comment: @whuber I am defining the true error as the difference between the polynomial fit and the true function without random error terms (sinusoidal). However, this true error diverges as I let the division on the interval (x-axis) into points increase.

Comment: That "true error" is not defined until (1) you specify a *compact* domain for the function and (2) you specify the metric you are using to compare two functions.

Answer (score 1):

The "total error" you are looking for may be something like the [distance between functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675833/find-the-distance-between-2-functions).

You are currently computing:

$$error = \Sigma (f(x_i) -g(x_i))^2 $$

This will, as you have found, not converge to a single answer when you vary your sampling 'increment'.

What you *should* be computing is something more like:

$$error = \Sigma (f(x_i) -g(x_i))^2 \Delta x $$

where $\Delta x$ is the 'increment' in $x$ you use to estimate the error.

This should produce the converging results that you expected.

Comment: That error function approaches 0 as I let $\Delta x$ approach 0, is that behavior expected?

Comment: I would not expect it to go to zero, no. Can you provide the functions that produce the blue and orange curves?